# How to resolve problematic vnc/xming clipboard interaction?

Tags: windows, emacs, vnc, clipboard, x-windows

I often have both a VNC client window and several X windows open (via Xming) at the same time on my Windows XP desktop.  When this  happens, the X windows, especially emacs and firefox, often lock up or behave erratically. I am pretty sure I have narrowed this down to contention over the clipboard.  I wasn't really able to find any options controlling this behavior in either Xming or VNC.  Is there a solution to this problem? Right now, I have to close VNC when I am actively using emacs...

Comment: Which VNC viewer are you using?

Comment: @peterMaxwell 4.1.3. xming is 6.9.0.31

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the clipboard might help, not sure if this'll work on XP, on Windows 7:
taskkill /IM rdpclip.exe /F
start /MIN rdpclip.exe
This has some more information [here](http://blog.offenders.org/?p=85).